# Finding the difference between the dates in months based on particular ID and solving in R

Tags: r, loops, date, foreach, logic

Below is my sample data set which has many unique `ID`'s and I have to find out the difference between the first occurrence and the second occurrence in the `First_Diff` column and the difference between the second occurrence and the third in `Second_Diff` column and so on. They are many occurrences in the table and trying to give a sample.

Input:

```
Date    ID
1/3/2006    209
1/3/2006    489
1/3/2006    502
1/3/2006    439
1/3/2006    534
1/3/2006    474
1/3/2006    566
1/3/2006    591
1/4/2006    209
1/4/2007    489
1/5/2007    502
1/7/2006    439
1/3/2008    534
1/3/2007    474
1/3/2008    566
1/7/2009    439
1/3/2009    534
1/3/2009    474
1/3/2010    566
```

Output:

```
ID  First_Diff  Second_Diff Third_DIff
209 1   0   0
489 13  0   0
502 14  0   0
439 3   0   0
534 24  0   0
474 12  0   0
566 24  12  0
591 0   0   0
```

Can anyone please help me in this. As this very complicated for me and did not able to solve this for my further findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help with your problem

```
# Create fake data frame
dates = c(rep(c("2015-01-09", "2015-02-09", "2015-03-08"), 3))
id  = c(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3))

df =data.frame(date = as.Date(dates), id = as.factor(id))
```

You can calculate the differences using `lag()` function

```
# Calculate difference between times
df = df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(datediff = difftime(date, lag(date)))
```

And then transform to wide format using `spread`

```
df_wide = df %>% spread(date, datediff) 

names(df_wide) <-  c("id", "first_diff", "second_diff", "third_diff")
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
      id first_diff second_diff third_diff
* <fctr>     <time>      <time>     <time>
1      A    NA days     31 days    27 days
2      B    NA days     31 days    27 days
3      C    NA days     31 days    27 days
```

Comment: I think you need to transform the format of the variable referred to Date. The variable that you create with the time differences works regardless of the number of observations for each id.

Comment: My` datediff` is giving a very long number which is not correct. Is there any means where I could get the `lag` in months

Comment: Yes. Using  `month()` from `lubridate` should let you extract the month from your date and then apply the lag.

Answer (score 0):

First use `ave` to create a `seq` column that is 0 for the first occurrence of any `ID`, 1 for the second and so on.

Then use `tapply` to create a matrix `mat` with each `ID` being a row and each `seq` being a column and the content being the number of months since the Epoch.
`as.yearmon` internally converts each date to a year + frac where jan = 0, feb = 1/12, etc., `tapply` will convert that to a number and multiplying by 12 gives the number of months.

Finally create the result by using the rownames of `mat` as the `ID` column and for the remaining columns difference the columns of `mat` appropriate.  We have used NA rather than 0 to indicate a value that cannot be calculated since otherwise we would not be able to distinguish two occurrences that are 0 months apart and a value that cannot be calculated.

```
library(zoo)

DF2 <- transform(DF, seq = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along) - 1)
mat <- with(DF2, 12 * tapply(Date, list(ID, seq), as.yearmon, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
cbind(ID = rownames(mat), as.data.frame(mat[, -1] - mat[, -ncol(mat)]))
```

giving:

```
     ID  1  2
209 209  1 NA
439 439  4 36
474 474 12 24
489 489 13 NA
502 502 14 NA
534 534 24 12
566 566 24 24
591 591 NA NA
```

### Variation

We could also write the above code in a magrittr pipeline:

```
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
   transform(seq = ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along) - 1) %>%
   with(12 * tapply(Date, list(ID, seq), as.yearmon, format = "%d/%m/%Y")) %>%
   { cbind(ID = rownames(.), as.data.frame(.[, -1] - mat[, -ncol(.)])) }
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Date    ID
1/3/2006    209
1/3/2006    489
1/3/2006    502
1/3/2006    439
1/3/2006    534
1/3/2006    474
1/3/2006    566
1/3/2006    591
1/4/2006    209
1/4/2007    489
1/5/2007    502
1/7/2006    439
1/3/2008    534
1/3/2007    474
1/3/2008    566
1/7/2009    439
1/3/2009    534
1/3/2009    474
1/3/2010    566"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```